# How to gsub \ in ruby array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, gsub

How to remove all `\` elements from the array?

Array of size 6:

```
data =
[
      " \"\"http://www.web1.com\\\"",
      "\"",
      " \"\"https://www.web2.com\\\"",
      "\"",
      " \"\"http://www.web3.com\\\"",
      "\"",
 ]
```

#### desired:

```
 ["www.web1.com", "www.web2.com", "www.web3.com"]
```

#### tried :

```
 data = 
 => [" \"\"http://www.web1.com\\\"", "\"", " \"\"https://www.web2.com\\\"", "\"", " \"\"http://www.web3.com\\\"", "\""] 
2.0.0-p353 :019 > data.each do |d| 
2.0.0-p353 :020 >     d.gsub!(/\+/,'')
2.0.0-p353 :021?>   end
 => [" \"\"http://www.web1.com\\\"", "\"", " \"\"https://www.web2.com\\\"", "\"", " \"\"http://www.web3.com\\\"", "\""] 
2.0.0-p353 :022 >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the result you expected.

```
data.grep(/https?:\/\/([^\\]*)/) {|v| v.match(/https?:\/\/([^\\]*)/)[1] }
```

But you have to know that `\` is used to escape the special char in the string.

`"\\"` has only one char that is `\`, `"\""` has only one char that is `"`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can get your desired output:

```
data.map { |e| e.gsub(/["\s\\\/]|(?:https?:\/\/)/,'') }.reject(&:empty?)
```

You iterate over data array and substitute element's contents that match regexp with `''`. Then you just drop empty strings.

Let me explain the regexp a little: `[...]` means group of characters, we will match any character from a group; `|` is `or` operator; `(?:)` is non-capuring group, so we must match whole `https://` or `http://`; `\s` means any whitespace character; `\\` and `\/` are escaped `\` and `/`.

Comment: Sure, hope that helps.

Comment: you can replace select{|e| !e.empty?} with reject{|e| e.empty?}

Comment: @Kavu What about a url like `http://www.htps.com/` or anything else which has `htps` char in the domain part :)

Comment: @xdazz yeah, it will totally fail :-D Need to improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can gsub all \ by doing:

```
your_string.gsub('\','')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.grep(/http/){|x|x.delete '\\\" '}
```